# How to check whether List<T>.Sort actually sorted something?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

Consider the following code:

```
class Employee : IComparable<Employee>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Employee other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
    }
}

void DoStuff()
{
    var e1 = new Employee() { Name = "Frank" };
    var e2 = new Employee() { Name = "Rizzo" };

    var lst = new List<Employee>() { e1, e2 };
    lst.Sort();
}
```

How do I know if the Sort method actually rearranged anything?  Bonus question: if it rearrange, how many things?

Comment: If one item moved from the end to the beginning, how many things were rearranged? 1 or all?

Comment: Don't trust the BCL, eh? :)

Comment: @JerKimball Haha, no, not that. I am dealing with a large, complicated code base where the .Sort is the perf bottleneck.  I suspect that the List<T> instances are already sorted and the method is just spinning its wheels.  I am looking for a quick way to determine that.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Any method will work for me.

Comment: Mind you, you need a stable sort to really give you information about sorting shuffling places. Unstable sorts like quick sorts can be less useful in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx You'd have to make a copy of the list before you sort it to compare it to, though.

```
List<Pet> pets1 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };
List<Pet> pets2 = new List<Pet> { pet1, pet2 };

bool equal = pets1.SequenceEqual(pets2);
```

Comment: Quick and painless.  TIL `SequenceEqual`

Comment: As an aside, this does not tell you why `List<T>.Sort` was slow. Likely your comparator is inefficient.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Not keeping track of how a comparer is comparing doesn't make it efficient. If anything, keeping track is less efficient unless you actually need it.

Comment: @Tim: I don't disagree, I just think the OP is asking the wrong question.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Ah, I didn't see his comment under his question where he said his Sort is slow.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have implemented your own comparer, why not track how many times it is called?

```
// naive, not thread safe, not exactly going to tell you much
static int compared = 0;
public int CompareTo(Employee other)
{
    compared++;
    return string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);
}
```

As another approach, why not switch to sorted input rather than sorting the entire list each time?

```
public void AddEmployee(Employee item)
{
    // keep in mind this may not always be faster than List<T>.Sort
    // but it should be.
    if (employees.Count > 1)
    {
        var index = employees.BinarySearch(item);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            employees.Insert(~index, item);
        }
    }
    else employees.Add(item);
}
```

Alternatively, use a sorted collection like [`SortedList<K,T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It might not sound as the nicest solution but why not log the result of `string.Compare`

```
public int CompareTo(Employee other)
{
    int result = string.Compare(this.Name, other.Name);

    Debug.WriteLine("Result of Compare of {0} and {1} is {2}", 
        this.Name, other.Name, result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What exactly would this tell me?

Comment: If it is 0 they are equal, if your this.Name starts lets say with A, and other.Name with B, you will get -1 and no order changes would be made, while the result of 1 would be the opposite and order replacement would occur.